# Functional Requirements vs Non Functional Requirements for a mobile web app

Tags: software-design, system-requirements, system-analysis

I am getting a bit confused about non functional requirements could anyone help me and let me know if the following seems correct

The functional requirements of this project is to create a mobile application that is:

- Cross platform compatible and works on most mobile browser
- Integrates a selected number of popular social networking sites in
  one place
- Communicates with social networking APIs
- Uses login and OAuth mechanisms to authorize
- Records and monitors social networking activity
- Stores the data locally Displays total statistics for the user

Non functional requirements

- Record statistics accurately
- Fast navigation
- Flexibility to choose which sites they want to integrate out of 3 and do not always have to use all 3. For example; the user should still be able to use Facebook and Twitter in the App and leave out YouTube (if they are not interested inYouTube).
- App should be able to function with chosen sites.
- Should be flexible in terms of being able to integrate other popular social networking  sites too
- Should be available to users to use anytime

Answer (score 1):

if you have a look on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475979/what-is-functional-and-non-functional-requirement), there is explained what non-functional rquirements are. In my mind the third point of your non-functional list is a functional requirment. Because this describes a functinality which the app should have. And the fourth and fith requirement depends also in the functional category I guess. But in this two cases I'm not 100% sure

Hope I could help you a bit

Comment: thanks! :) but doesn't flexibility come under non functional as in here http://www.outsystems.com/blog/2013/03/the-truth-about-non-functional-requirements-nfrs.html

Comment: Yeah thats right, but your requirment doesen't only describe the felxibility of you application. It's also describe the opportunity for the user to choose which sites he wants to use. Due that I would say it's more an functional requirement.

Answer (score 1):

to really know which are the functional requirements and which are the non functional requirements, you should check it with your client ( Business Owner ), 
for example ( using your data ):
- fast navigation could be a functional requirement for some clients. lets say you are developing a news feeder application, for some clients, this is a requirement and should be stated in the analysis phase my friend.
- security might *not* be a functional requirement, for example lets say a news feeder application, a log-in attributes might not be required.

so, my advice, be flexible about your opinions, though try to be so sure about your data before you start.
(if you are the business owner - i mean if you are the supplier of the data for your mobile application - then try to ask some of your friends and co-workers for which data might be essential for you to go on.)