# Do i have to include initializing and declaring parts in the code as functional requirements?

Tags: java, functional-programming

```
//Declaring variables
    int level;
    int strBonus, dexBonus, conBonus, _intBonus, wisBonus, chaBonus;

    //Initializing
    conBonus = 0;
    String choice = null;
```

Do I have to put these as the functional requirements.What are exactly the functional requirements

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475979/what-is-the-difference-between-functional-and-non-functional-requirement

Comment: **No**. Functional requirements are simple; ***what*** should the thing do? For example, the functional requirement of a shoe is that it protects your foot; that might be a sandal or a sneaker. Functionally though...

Comment: That means i have to add prompting from the user and calculation stuff only right??

Answer (score 0):

Functional requirements define what the system or application will do - specifically in the context of an external interaction (with a user, or with another system).

When placing a new order, the system shall display the total cost and require confirmation from the user. That is a functional requirement; it describes a function of the system.

refer [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_requirement)