# Why do we differentiate between functional and non functional requirements

Tags: architecture, requirements

I understand the [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475979/what-is-the-difference-between-functional-and-non-functional-requirements) between functional and non functional requirements.

- What I never understood is, why do we make this differentiation?
- (Rephrased) When I design a solution, why is it useful to distinguish between these two?

Comment: It's just a way to structure and organize the requirements. You don't need to follow it if you have another good structure.

Comment: Maybe, but it is such a widespread approach, I kinda expect there to be a really good reason why we use exactly this method.

Comment: Non-functional requirements are often forgotten. So there's an emphasis on them. It's less about the differentiation and more about ensuring that non-functional requirements are not forgotten.

Answer (score 1):

They are usually raised by different stakeholders. The quality attributes (what you called non-functionals) are mostly raised by the technology people and are somehow assumed by business owners